# Добавление изображения используя pyautogui python3

Tags: python, pyautogui

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой при создании графического приложения на python3. Использую библиотеку pyautogui.
Задача добавить изображение на экран приложения. Подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

гляньте [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907314/python-how-can-i-find-an-image-on-screen-by-using-pyautogui-lib) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41341052/10547102) а самый точный ответ [здесь](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html)